# finding a minimum bound for sum of coefficients of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

We have the following polynomial function:
$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_n x^n$; $a_i=\{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$.
We know that $f(2)=A$. By having that, what we can say about the sum of the coefficients, or $f(1)$? I would like to find a minimum for $f(1)$ based on $n$ and $A$.

---

**Updated description of the above problem**:

Suppose we have the following polynomial:
$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + ... + a_{k-2}x^{k-2} + a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + ... + a_{k+p-3}x^{k+p-3} + a_{k+p-2}x^{k+p-2}$

In which:

$k,p\geq 1$, and $\in N$,

$a_i \in Z$ for $0\leq i \leq k-2$, and $a_i \in N$ or 0 for $k-1\leq i \leq k+p-2$. Also, for $k-1\leq i \leq k+p-2$, $a_i$ is monotonic decreasing, meaning that $a_i \geq a_j $ for $i \leq j$.

We know that $f(2) = A = 2^k(2^p-1)$. By having that, what we can say about $f(1) = \sum_{n=0}^{k+p-2}a_i$. Does it have any minimum?. More specifically, I would like to prove that $[\sum_{n=0}^{k+p-2}a_i] \geq p$.

Comment: When you say $a_i=\{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$, do you mean to imply only that the $a_i$ are positive or negative integers or zero?  (In which case, $a_i\in$ would be clearer than $a_i=$.) Or do you mean to say that something more is to be assumed known about the $a_i$?

Comment: I man ai is positive or negative integers or it is 0.

Comment: Seems like you have many degrees of freedom,it should be trivial that $f(1)$ can be as small as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can say unless $f$ is constant. Given any $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}$ you can find an integer polynomial of any positive degree such that $f(1) = B$ and $f(2) = A$.

Set $c_0 = B$ and then choose $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n = A$$
Then if 
$$p(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n-1}c^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1x + c_0,$$
we have $p(0) = B$ and $p(1) = A$. Then set $f(x) = p(x - 1)$ so that $f(1) = B$ and $f(2) = A$.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to simplify the problem. In the real problem, there are some restrictions on the coefficients. So, a better description of the $f(x)$ and its coefficients are: $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...a_{k−2}x^{k−2}+a_{k−1}x^{k−1}+...+a_{k+p−2}x^{k+p−2}$and $A=2^k∗(2^p−1)$. And, $a_i$ are in $Z$ for $i$ from $0$ to $k−2$. From $k−1$ to the end, they are positive integers or $0$ and they are monotonic decreasing (i.e. $a_i$ is smaller or equal to $a_j$ for $i>=j$.) $k$ is a positive integer equal or greater than $1$.